# htop isn't displaying consistent information

Tags: python, tmux, htop

I'm running a computationally intense serial python script, and htop is giving me an inconsistent information. It shows that a thread is almost 100% in use, but that python isn't using any CPU power. Does anyone know why python isn't listed as using a ton of CPU power? I am using tmux to split the screens so you can see all the information.

[image: screenshot of my code, the script running, and htop]

Answer (score 3):

The standard Python interpreter (CPython) is single-threaded. This is required by what's called the "Global Interpreter Lock" (GIL) that allows no real concurrent access to Python objects at the same time. See e.g. https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock for details.

Therefore a regular Python script (which does not use e.g. the `multiprocessing` library to spawn multiple interpreter processes) can only run on one single CPU thread at a time. This means on a processor with four threads (dual core with hyper threading), it can only consume at most 25% of the total CPU time summed over all threads, or 100% of a single CPU thread.

So as htop reports, your script is using almost 100% of one CPU thread, so it is actually running at the maximum speed it can. Nothing unusual to see here.

If the script is yours, you could try and adapt or rewrite it to parallelize the work by using the [`multiprocessing` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) as mentioned before. Not all code can be parallelized though. If you can not really change the script, you'll have to accept the way it runs.

Comment: I get that, but I'm wondering why htop's description of what processes are using what % of CPU say's python is only using 0.6% CPU, when it's clearly using almost an entire core.

Comment: There's one Python process running on 95.8% of a core. The others might be asleep waiting for IO or blocked by something else, I don't know.